# Express route sign up Ajax returning POST http://localhost:3004/signup/ 404

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm getting a POST http://localhost:3004/signup/ 404 when submitting an Ajax post to my express `/signup/` route. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to node!

server.js

```
const pg = require('pg')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const knex = require('./knex')
const express =require('express')
var path = require('path');
const router = express.Router()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3004
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).send('working')
})

router.get('/user', (req, res, next) => {
    knex('user').then(data=>{
        res.status(200).send(data)
    })
})

router.post('/signup/', (req, res, next) => {
    knex('user').insert({
        name:req.body.name,
        lastName:req.body.nameLast,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password
    },'*')
    .then(user=>{
        res.status(204).send({id:user[0].id})
    })
})





app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const status = err.status || 404
    res.status(status).json({ error: err })
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).json({ error: { status: 404, message: 'Not found' 
    }})
})

const listener = () => `Listening on port ${port}!`
app.listen(port, listener)
```

signup.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3004'
     $( "#submit" ).on( "click", function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        const name = $( "#name" ).val();
        const last = $( "#nameLast" ).val()
        const email = $( "#email" ).val()
        const password = $( "#password" ).val()

        $.ajax({
            url: `/signup/`,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              name: name,
              last: last,
              email: email,
              password: password
            },
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = '/index.html'
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Have you tried making `GET` request with AJAX? Does it work?

Comment: Yeah, my get request for all user info works.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, but try removing extra `/` from your path in both ajax request and node js file. I.e. from `/signup/` to `/signup`.

Comment: If the above does not work, try `console.log`ging right before `res.status(204).send({id:user[0].id})`

Comment: Have I misunderstood something? If you use the solution in my answer it will work. I tested the client-side code too.

Comment: I console.log(req.body) and when I submit the form on the frontend I get undefined for req.body in my terminal. I really appreciate your help, thank you!!

Comment: @JosephGrounds That's because you're not parsing the content. I updated my answer with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the router with

```
app.use('/', router);
```

You can add it right above

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const status = err.status || 404
    res.status(status).json({ error: err })
})
```

for example. It's explained in the official [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) (last section).

---

To be able to read `req.body` you have to enable the body-parser middleware. Add

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

right below

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Make sure you add the lines before the routes are defined. body-parser parses JSON and x-www-form-urlencoded content when you add those two lines. You are sending x-www-form-urlencoded in your ajax request.

Comment: Thanks, router is now working as opposed to app.post unfortunately it's still not working